# Issue with two sed replacements in a bash script and looping over many input files and outputting them

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two replacements in a file that I want to implement from a bash script.

So far I have a shell script called `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# 1. change Hybridization REF to Hybridization_REF
# 2. change Composite Element REF to Composite_Element_REF

sed 's/Hybridization REF/Hybridization_REF/g' test_input.txt
sed 's/Composite Element REF/Composite_Element_REF/' test_input.txt
```

From the command line I then run `$ test.sh > test_out.txt`

**Questions**

1. This doesn't quite work because I find is that the first `sed` replacement is completed fine but the second one is not. Is there a way for me to modify the script so that both `sed` replacements go as planned?
2. Ideally I want to automate this for over 1000 files, which are all in the same folder and share the same prefix `tumMeth` and then output these 1000 input files to 1000 corresponding output files with the same name. Is there a way to incorporate a loop into the above script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both `sed` commands into one and run a loop for your input file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in tumMeth*; do
    sed 's/Hybridization REF/Hybridization_REF/g; s/Composite Element REF/Composite_Element_REF/' "$f" > "$f.out"
done
```

Comment: In the same loop, I've been trying to call an awk script as follows: `for f in TCGAOV*; do  
 sed 's/Hybridization REF/Hybridization_REF/g; s/Composite Element REF/Composite_Element_REF/' "$f" > "final.$f"
         awk_methreformat.sh "final.$f" > :final.$f"
done` but this just results in an empty file. Is my syntax for calling the awk script wrong? Commenting out the awk script call that I added produces the output I need for the first step, so it's definitely the line I added that is the problem. I'm using a Mac OS X.

Comment: Hope `awk` command is on a separate line. I haven't seen awk script so can't tell you further why that is not working.

Comment: Yes the awk script call is on a separate line. I adapted the awk script from the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697655/how-to-selectively-remove-columns-and-rows-with-bash-or-python)

Comment: Difficult to tell what is wrong. You can run just `bash -x awk_methreformat.sh "final.$f"` inside the loop to see debug output.

Comment: So this issue is with the awk script, which is weird since it was working previously: `+ NR == 1 '{'
../../../methods/meth_ma_gene/awk_methreformat.sh: line 3: NR: command not found
../../../methods/meth_ma_gene/awk_methreformat.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token \`('
../../../methods/meth_ma_gene/awk_methreformat.sh: line 5: \`    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {'`

Comment: I suggest creating a new question for this additional awk problem as this answer is sed specific.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical way of calling multiple sed statements in a file is to put them in a sed script.

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/Hybridization REF/Hybridization_REF/g
s/Composite Element REF/Composite_Element_REF/
```

Store the above code in a file, say `substitution.sed`, make it executable by doing `chmod u+x substitution.sed` and execute like

```
substitution.sed < test_input.txt > test_out.txt
```